Would it make sense for an entity who can control tangible and/or intangible matterials be able to manipulate electricity but not light
I have this idea about people with "Psionic" power.
Psionics are primarily beings able to emit-, and/or manipulate a special energy field from within that takes physical form. They can extend it outward to pick up various materials like picking it up with their own hands with approximately 3 to even 10 times the strength of their actual physical body depending on the individual. Everything they do affects their own body and if they go past their limit they can risk their bodies going through the same problems as if overdoing it in terms of exercising (fatigue, muscle aches, death via exhaustion, etc) and this energy can be used only in two forms; tangible and intangible.
Those that can affect tangible materials(rock, metal, etc) can either move it around or straight up crush it by applying pressure through their energy field, however due to psionic energy being more equivalent to a physical extention of the body like an arm, the heavier the object the harder it'll be to hold onto it let alone pick it up and if it's granulated like sand for example the user will have to pick up the chunks of sand with some it dripping out or if they actually want to do anything with the sand they would have pick up the individual grains of sand which runs the risks of tiring out the user dependingon individual power and the portion of sand being used.
Those whose energy type affects intangible materials (gas, air, etc) can grab intangible materials including air (only small portions of the air though) and can condense it to a certain degree, however the larger in body the amount air or gas the psionic user tries to grab, the harder it is to maintain, as well it becoming more strenuous to hold onto and condense, and they can't affect the individual gasses when it's a mix like say for example how air is made out of oxygen, nitrogen etc, they can't separate or grab said individual gasses.
One rule I espcially wanted to set up is that regardless of what said psyionic energy user affects, they can't grab light with their psionic energy, period, simply because I felt it would be a little too much in terms of power.
The problem is I did want to set it up where psionic energy can affect electricity (grab it, condense it etc) and wanted to set it up where the user can only affect electricity from outside sources such as from a taser or a fusebox so no grabbing and moving electrons.
So now I'm left wondering: does it make sense that psionic energy can be used to grab electricity but not light, let alone if there is a way to make sense of it, after all light and electricity are practically the same thing (energy). They aren't exactly one of the three states of matter (solid, liquid, gas) and I don't want to use the excuse of it being too overabundant to simply grab with psionic energy since intangible users can grab air in small portions (which is everywhere).

This question has potential - but I think you need to format your question a bit and refine what you are asking.

Aside from formatting, there are two main problems with the question as it stands.

Whether a made-up power's limitations "make sense" or not are up to you.  2) We do not know what you mean by "control" light.  Invisibility?  Weapons-grade lasers?  Holograms?  Illumination?  Note that the ability to manipulate matter (with sufficient control) and create electricity makes creating illumination trivial.


Did you mean Psionics? Also, you will want to be more clear with the question you are asking. Maybe state the exact question to be answered in bold at the end. I would also argue that light and electricity don't have to be the same thing, and would like to ask you to go a bit further in depth about how electricity is a tangible material with these powers.

The way this works is somewhat unclear. What are the cutoff points where it goes from say, solid to liquid? How fine a grain of sand is liquid, if any? Are there people who don't think they have powers, because they've never come across plasma? Further explanation would be great.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Currently you're asking does it make sense for magic to grab one thing and not another. You get to decide all the rules of magic in your world that is the only way to provide a definitive answer to this question. Questions asking for personal opinions or that ask us to build your world for you are not appropriate for this site.

Option 1: Light is too fast to grab
Everybody knows that light move at the fastest speed available to our version of physics, the speed of light, so it being impossible to grab make sense intuitively.
Now, technically speaking, electricity also moves at this speed, but this changes when you make it move through a medium, like copper wires or water, where it's speed drops enough for us to handwave that now its a speed we can grab and abuse.
Option 2: Light moves through air, which we already established is hard to handle and separate
You already told us that they can't affect the individual gasses when it's a mix, and gas molecules are gigantic compared to the photons that make light, so separating them is gonna be way more impossible than just separating the air into nitrogen and oxygen.
Option 3: Photons disrupt the psionic fields
The photons interact with the psionic field in a negative way, not enough to completely stop them, but enough that trying to manipulate them is the equivalent of putting a stove inside a freezer. This also open up the possibility of "containing" your psionic users with huge LEDs.
All these options give you a good excuse as to why they can manipulate electricity when in a taser or fusebox medium but not straight up lighting
Hope they help

Hm that actually makes sense, yeah so it's like a combination of problems  such as speed,  light technically being part of air and just straight just straight photons mess up the power, yeah that could work, plus that LED detail is actually a good idea, also I've actually been tinkering with the idea that one individual person found a way to have their psionic energy affect light by simply coateing themselves in their field so as to basically render themselves effectively invisible but just can't do anything like make sword, but this renders themself blind, something light that

@Vilarinof yeah that's what I was thinking as an explanation for electricity manipulation, since lightning strikes so quickly no can grab on time to do anything with it as well being a little overabundant to affective affect it, but yeah relative speeds is something I was thinking on
